# ArcGIS DLL is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains error?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, installation

I have ArcGIS 10.3 running on Windows 7... and I have recently come across an error that I have not encountered before. After starting ArcMap, I receive an error stating:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\bin\GxRaster.dll is either
>   not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error. Try installing
>   the program again using the original installation media, or contact
>   your system administrator

Has anyone come across this before?

ArcMap continues to open but I cannot even do anything as basic as adding data before the program shuts down. The closest I've found via Google is:

http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/28065

but it covers a different set of circumstances.

Comment: Sounds like filesystem corruption.  Have you tried uninstall/reinstall?

Comment: we are trying to avoid doing that if at all possible. There were a few Windows patches installed right before this started happening, I am hoping that restoring to a point prior to those patches will at least help me in determining the cause.

Comment: Uninstall/reinstall takes 10-15 minutes.  Exercising restore points will take a lot longer than that, and if it is filesystem corruption, the DLL will still be corrupt when you're done.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @Vince, this sounds like file system corruption so I suggest that you:

1. locate the same download or disk that you used originally - you can always download it again.
2. either repair your installation, or uninstall/reinstall it (which should only take about 10-15 minutes)